# Load font file from CSS file

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I tried to run font file from CSS file:

This code is working fine:

```
  src: url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0") format("woff"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
```

But this code is not working:

```
  src: url("#{resource['fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0']}") format("embedded-opentype"), url("#{resource['fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0']}") format("woff2"), url("#{resource['fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0']}") format("woff"), url("#{resource['fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0']}") format("truetype"), url("#{resource['fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular']}") format("svg");
```

What is the proper way to load font file?

Comment: why not load it on the xhtml page?

Comment: I need to load it into CSS file